# Blue box on select components page

Tags: inno-setup

On the select components page, A blue box is there for a parent instead of a check mark. How can I make it always be a check mark? I have found an example on google, but I cant post images yet.

Here is the example: http://winscp.net/eng/data/media/screenshots/installer_components.png

Comment: That *blue box* is a check box in *indeterminate* (or sometimes called *mixed*) state. It is displayed for the parent component when its children are in both states (when there's at least one child component that is checked and one that is unchecked). But that's correct from the UX point of view. Why do you want to go against that ? Are you sure you want your components to be in such hierarchy in the first place ?

Comment: I just thought it looked strange. I don't have to do it that way. What I would like to do, is have a page after the components page with option check box to install another component. I have no idea how to do it yet though. I'm very new to inno setup and have minimal coding experience.

Comment: That's what the `[Tasks]` section is for.